# SQL CASE if date was introduced as YYYY-DD-MM to convert it as YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql-server, date, substring, case-when

Hi i am trying to solve a problem because i get a

```
'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'
```

So then i found out that it was because a date was like this '2018-22-10' and the format i have is YYYY-MM-DD so i was trying to make a case for this case, i found this code that might help

```
WHEN SUBSTRING([DateAchat],6, 2) > 12 THEN ([DateAchat], '%Y-%m-%d')                        .strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


to_date(T1.[DateAchat],'YYYYMMDD');


FORMAT T1.[DateAchat](getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd ')
```

In DateAchat is there the date info is stored

Comment: The [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) function returns a string. To compare it with a number you must convert the string to numerical data type (to integer in your case).

Comment: I cast it later
CAST ([DateAchat] AS DATETIME2), i want it to grab the 2 digits of theday and change it for the one in the months so it ends up like YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: You can change the desired format using [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: i dont want to change all the format of it i just want it to change it if  ([DateAchat],6, 2) > 12

Comment: DateAchat is a  Nvarchar

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. You're going to assume that *only* when the middle piece is > 12 then the wrong format was entered? What if I enter `2018-11-12` when I meant `2018-12-11`? Why is this column a string in the first place? Why are you accepting user input in whatever format they type? How will you prevent `2018-13-13`? This is just a disaster all around.

Comment: it only would happened if it would be like this 2018-16-05 then the result would be 2018-05-11

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Embrace the coming doom. If the format is inconsistent, you can't possibly know when to convert except for the obvious ones. As Aaron indicated, you can't know if 11/12 is Novermber 12 or December 11.

Comment: its a warranty, so it is just for not to get an error when the scripts runs so i am now using a case like the next one : CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[DateAchat],6, 2) > 12 THEN RIGHT(T1.[DateAchat],4)+'-'+LEFT(T1.[DateAchat],2)+'-'+substring(T1.[DateAchat],6,2) end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SET DATEFORMAT` combined with `TRY_CONVERT` function

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (d1 nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('2018-22-10'), ('2018-10-22'), ('2018-10-10');
SET DATEFORMAT ydm
SELECT d2
FROM (SELECT COALESCE(try_convert(datetime, d1, 120), try_convert(datetime, d1)) AS d2
      FROM @t) t1 
WHERE d2 IS NOT NULL
```

Result

```
d2
-----------------------
2018-10-22 00:00:00.000
2018-10-22 00:00:00.000
2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
```